# check if map exists in vimScript

Tags: vim

I am trying to check if a mapping exists, and if true, unmap it. If I try to do it without checking it runs into error and exits. I guess I can also try to catch the error and add exception, but I can't find how to do it neither.

I tried:

```
if exists("map jjj")
    unmap jjj
endif
```

But it returns that `map jjj` exists (even if not true) because if I run in normal mode

```
:map jjj
```

it returns `n  j      * gj`. That is, it returns `j` map exists.

I don't have further ideas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `maparg("jjj")`, from the `:help maparg`:

```sh
maparg({name} [, {mode} [, {abbr} [, {dict}]]])         *maparg()*

        When {dict} is omitted or zero: Return the rhs of mapping
        {name} in mode {mode}.  The returned String has special
        characters translated like in the output of the ":map" command
        listing.


        When there is no mapping for {name}, an empty String is
        returned.  When the mapping for {name} is empty, then "<Nop>"
        is returned.
```

It will exactly match the `{name}` of the mapping.